# c# taglibs edit mp4 file rating and subtitle

Tags: c#, taglib-sharp

i am trying to edit an mp4 files Title, subtitle, rating, tags and comments.
So far this code works for editing the title:

```
file.Tag.Title = TheVars.Title;
```

but there is no .Subtitle option.
also for rating i can make this work with mp3s:

```
TagLib.Id3v2.Tag.DefaultVersion = 3;
TagLib.Id3v2.Tag.ForceDefaultVersion = true;
Tag Tag = file.GetTag(TagTypes.Id3v2);
TagLib.Id3v2.PopularimeterFrame frame = TagLib.Id3v2.PopularimeterFrame.Get((TagLib.Id3v2.Tag)Tag, "WindowsUser", true);
frame.Rating = 255;
```

But when trying to edit a .mp4 rating it returns a null error.

pls help Thanks!

Comment: MP4 Tags are not ID3v2.